# Python - NLP - convert iter(iter(tree)) to list(tree)

Tags: python, list, parsing, iterator, nlp

I have a parser function which returns `iter(iter(tree))`.

```
parsedSentence = parser.raw_parse_sents([sentence],False)
```

How can I convert the parsedSentence type to list(tree)  and access 1st element of that list.

*I've already tried `list(parser.raw_parse_sents([sentence],False))` but it's not converting the result to list.*

**Edited:**

```
s1 = parsedSentence[0]
t1 = Tree.convert(s1)
positions = t1.treepositions()
```

Here it throws an error:

```
'listiterator' object has no attribute 'treepositions'
```

Thank You.

Comment: If you are not getting a list, what else are you getting?

Comment: It is still considering the result as Iterator, say listiterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference that how many time you used `iter` on an iterable object you can simply convert it to list by calling `list` function.

```
>>> l =[6, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2]
>>> list(iter(iter(iter(iter(l)))))
[6, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2]
```

But if you just want to get the fist item you don't need to use `list` function you can simply use `next` method on an iterator or `next()` built-in function (in python 3.X you can just use built-in function `next()`) to get the forst item :

```
>>> iter(iter(l)).next()
6
>>> iter(iter(iter(l))).next()
6
>>> iter(iter(iter(iter(l)))).next()
6
```

Now about your problem if you didn't get a `list` after calling `list` after calling it surely it's not an iterator it would be another object type that you need to get its items based on how its  [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.%5F%5Fgetitem%5F%5F) method has been implemented.

Based on your edit `t1` is a list iterator object and doesn't has attribute `treepositions` you can loop over it's items and then call those `treepositions` attribute:

```
s1 = parsedSentence[0]
t1 = Tree.convert(s1)
positions = [item.treepositions() for item in t1]
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3, the `next` method on iterator objects is renamed to `__next__`. A better way of getting at in either version is to use the builtin `next` function: `next(iterator)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have an idea that list(iter) would convert it into list. But I still get the same error :
'listiterator' object has no attribute 'treepositions'

Comment: Did you have tried to use the attribute `treepositions` on result?

Comment: Updated my question. pl. check it

Comment: That's a good catch ! I recently updated my nltk library, previously the code which I had never caused an issue, ever since I updated (this evening), am facing this type conversion issue. Now that gives a similar error else where too : 'listiterator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Answer (score 1):

Finally, Issue was resolved by changing

```
parser.raw_parse_sents([sentence],False)
```

to

```
parser.raw_parse(sentence)
```

Thanks to everyone who contributed their time.